# Error while setting up a IRC server at make command

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, irc

When trying to setup IRC on a Ubuntu 18.04 vps it shows this error.
(This error shows when running command make)

```
parse.o: In function `parse':
/root/IRC/src/parse.c:356: undefined reference to `parse_addlag'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Which IRC server are you trying to compile (there are dozens); which version; what commands did you use to build it; and why are you compiling it instead of installing from Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: unrealircd i don't really know the version

Comment: Unrealircd 3.2.x

Comment: But you downloaded the specific version in the first place... (Is there a good reason you chose 3.2.x? That's several years old by now.)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, edit parse.c and remove that inline from function definition.

`inline void parse_addlag`
become
`void parse_addlag`